# pthread_create :: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void *(*)(void *)' with an rvalue of type 'void *'

Tags: c++, macos, pthreads

I'm trying to pass a namespace function to pthread_create, but compiler is giving me errors, i have googled, searched in stackoverflow, but i couldn't fix my issue:

```
#include <pthread.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#include <iostream>
namespace SBProcThreads
{
  void ProcThread(void* defArg)
  {
    std::cout<<"### :"<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<":   ThreadId  :"<<(pthread_self())->__sig<<": ###"<<std::endl;
  }
}


int main()
{
  pthread_t pThreadId;
  ::pthread_create(&pThreadId,NULL,(void*)&SBProcThreads::ProcThread,NULL);
}
```

I don't want to pass any arguments, i have even removed void* defArg and tried giving 4th argument in ::pthread_create function, but still it's giving me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function signature for pthread_create requires a function that returns `void *`.  Also, `pthread_t` returned from `pthread_self()` should be treated opaquely.  Both of these changes are reflected below and compile on my machine:

```
#include <pthread.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#include <iostream>
namespace SBProcThreads
{
    void * ProcThread(void* defArg)
    {
        std::cout<<"### :"<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<":   ThreadId  :"<<(pthread_self())<<": ###"<<std::endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
      pthread_t pThreadId;
      ::pthread_create(&pThreadId,NULL,SBProcThreads::ProcThread,NULL);
}
```

UPDATE: There are some other issues with your program as well.  For example, it's very likely that main will exit before your thread runs.  You should join on your thread if you want to make sure it exits first.  Using raw pthreads is a great way to learn about threads but can be very very painful compared to some of the pre-existing frameworks out there - try boost::thread or std::thread if you want to just get up and running with as little hassle as possible.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, i'll try the compilation in my machine and update. And the code is just part of my application. I have a while loop in my main() which does something independently.  I understand using frameworks would be easy, but i want to learn more about pThreads, so i don't mind being it painful.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to either declare it so it doesn't need a cast:

```
  void *ProcThread(void* defArg)

  pthread_t pThreadId;
  ::pthread_create(&pThreadId,NULL,SBProcThreads::ProcThread,NULL);
```

Or cast it to the required form:

```
int main()
{
  pthread_t pThreadId;
  ::pthread_create(&pThreadId,NULL,(void*(*)(void*))&SBProcThreads::ProcThread,NULL);
}
```